# How to deal with settings on first load without crashing

Tags: ios, swift

First time I load my app I need to set some values in my Settings, but as I load my settings, the app crashes because my settings attempt to fill themselves in with the current values... all of which are somesort of nullpointer or whatever. In this specific situation, im trying to display the contents of a UIPickerView.

```
 var possibleDigit = Int(SettingsManager.shared.zoneVibrateCounts[0])
```

SettingsManager.shared.zoneVibrateCounts contains an array full of values. The array is not populated in anyway on first load. What I need is to be able to check if SettingsManager.shared.zoneVibrateCounts has any contents before I attempt to access its data. How can I do such a thing? Is more code necessary?

EDIT

Here is declare my arrayOfZoneVibrations

```
var arrayOfZoneVibrations: [Int]!
```

Ya

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if pickerView.tag == 1
    {
           SettingsManager.shared.timerDelay = row + 1
    timerDelayTextField.text = getTitle(row)
            timerDelayTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else
    {
        arrayOfZoneVibrations[pickerView.tag - 2] = row + 1
        SettingsManager.shared.zoneVibrateCounts = arrayOfZoneVibrations
    }

}
```

Here is how I access the SettingsManager part

```
var zoneVibrateCounts: [Int] {
    get {
        return  uDefaults.array(forKey: ZONES)  as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
    }
    set (value) {
        uDefaults.set(value, forKey: ZONES)
    }
}
```

And here is the definition for ZONES

```
private let ZONES               = "zones"
```

Comment: If you are using `UserDefaults`, look into the `registerDefaults` method.

Comment: What type of values are in your `zoneVibrateCounts` array? If you need to create an `Int` for whatever value is there, why isn't it already an array of `Int`?

Comment: Sorry I'm just a beginner. It is a value of Ints.. It looks like guards or if let are my options according to some googled samples but I'm getting this error. Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'

Comment: If `zoneVibrateCounts` is an array of `Int`, then why do you attempt to create an `Int` from the `Int`?

Comment: possibleDigit is simply to acquire the value of zoneVibrateCounts[0] in Int format

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Let's make this easier. Please update your question to include the relevant code showing your `SettingsManager zoneVibrationCounts` property and include the code that populates it.

Comment: K! Done! Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use `Int(SettingsManager.shared.zoneVibrateCounts[0])` since `SettingsManager.shared.zoneVibrateCounts[0]` is already an `Int`. So that can simply be written as:

```
var possibleDigit = SettingsManager.shared.zoneVibrateCounts[0]
```

Now, since it is possible that `SettingsManager.shared.zoneVibrateCounts` can be an empty array, you need to avoid directly accessing the non-existent index.

If you simply want some default value (such as `0`) if the array is empty, then you should do:

```
var possibleDigit = SettingsManager.shared.zoneVibrateCounts.first ?? 0
```

Feel free to replace the `0` after the `??` with whatever default makes sense for your app.

If you don't want to use a default value, but instead want to take a different action if the error is empty, then you should do:

```
if let firstCount = SettingsManager.shared.zoneVibrateCounts.first {
    // do something with firstCount
} else {
    // the array is empty, act accordingly
}
```

Or you can do:

```
guard let firstCount = SettingsManager.shared.zoneVibrateCounts.first else {
    return
}

// do something with firstCount
```